# When I load image and text, block click tab several seconds, why?

Tags: android

I do this in the create method on the activity for the second tab

```
public void infoTabs(){

    //tab1: it works well
    .......

    // tab 2:
    image.setImageResource(panel.getPhoto());
    String infoCasilla = panel.getInfoText();
    informacionCasilla.setText(infoCasilla);
}
```

Then when I press the second tab, it takes 3-4 seconds to load the image and text and is locked up showing this content tab.
Can you think of any idea as to prevent it from being blocked those seconds?
thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If your photo large , it could take a lot of time (i.e. 3-4 sec) to load image into imageButton(or ImageView,whatever you using). You should load it in worker(background) thread, not in ui thread (like you do it for now). So use Separate Thread like this:

```
 new Thread(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                 image.post(new Runnable(){
                     public void run() {
                       image.setImageResource(panel.getPhoto());            
                      }
                  }
            }
       }).start();
```

Or use [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso) or [Fresco](https://github.com/facebook/fresco) libs, that load image in separate thread for you.

Comment: Get the tab is not blocked thanks to thread, but now almost all images not shown me, leaving black background without loading anything or show anything